# 'send_data' does not correspond with end of AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, csv

I am generating a large CSV file using backend Ruby code for database queries, and then sending that data via `send_data` as a named CSV file.  It may take up to 12 minutes before the popup that says to view or save the file shows.

The owner has requested that I place a "We are compiling your file" pop-up to display in the meantime.  I tried using an AJAX call along the line of:

```
$('ul#download-csv li a').on('click', function() {
  $("body").addClass("loading");
  $('body').append('<p class="waiting">Preparing file for download.</p>');
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    },
    async: false
  })
  .done(function (data) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
  })
  .fail(function () {
    alert('We encountered an error in processing your request');
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
  });
});
```

As expected, the loading class is removed once the AJAX call is completed after about 6 minutes.  However, for another 6 minutes, the window just sits there before the pop-up appears to save/open the file.  What is causing the additional delay?

This is the Ruby controller:

```
def download_csv_file
  x_model = X.new
  x_file_name = ((params[:list]).upcase).to_s
  list = List.select('id').where(list_abbreviation: x_file_name)
  x_array = Array.new(0)
  fname = x_file_name + ".csv"
  csvFile = []
  query = Y.joins(:z).select('id').where('z.fk_x_id = ?', chemical_list[0])
  query.each do |i|
    x_query = x_model.get_list_item_for_download(i)
    x_array.push(x_query) if !x_query.blank?
  end
  csvFile.push "HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6,HEADER7\n"
  x_array.each do |i|
    csvFile.push "#{i['x_1'].to_s},#{i['x_2'].to_s},\"#{i['x_3'].to_s}\",#{i['x_4'].to_s},\"#{i['x_5'].to_s}\"\n"
  end
  send_data csvFile.join, filename: fname, content_type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

This is the Ruby model:

```
def get_list_item_for_download(id)
  @result_hash = Hash.new(0)

  query = Y.joins(:a, :b).select('y.id as y_id, y.c1, y.c2, y.c3, a.id as a_id, a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, min(z.c2) as z_level').where('y.id = ?', id)

  (query[0]).attributes.each {|var| @result_hash[var[0].to_sym] = var[1]}

  return @result_hash.as_json
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the built-in [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to generate the CSV content. It's not exactly a trivial [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2), and is likely to bite you when you least expect it, especially when dealing with strings containing double-quotes and/or commas.

Comment: It's hard to say what could case the delays. When you say "large CSV file", how large is it? How big is your host that generates the data CPU and memory wise? Where is the database hosted? On the same machine or a different one? Are you streaming the CSV to the client's browser where it's cached prior to being saved? We need a better idea of the problem. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]".

Comment: Regarding some of your questions, I am not sure.  I know the databases are on different servers.  The CSV is not cached, since the items from the database are changed regularly.

Comment: The CSV is 247.1 KB.

Comment: 247.1K is not big at all. You're using `to_s` in a lot of places where it shouldn't be necessary, such as `((params[:list]).upcase).to_s`. If you can use `upcase` on it it's a string already. Also it's not necessary to use `to_s` on values that are being interpolated into a variable, such as `"#{i['x_1'].to_s}..."` because Ruby automatically will convert the values to strings. Individual `to_s` are useful when necessary, but frivolous use wastes CPU slowing your code. Removing them might not solve the problem but it'll result in better code.